# Firebase Emulator Cloud Functions + PubSub subscribe to production topics

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, emulation, google-cloud-pubsub

There is a service that is publishing messages to my Pub/Sub. Via CLI, I know it is receiving properly the messages.

I want to react correspondingly to those messages. However, I want to develop my subscription, via Cloud Functions, in development environment (firebase emulator), so I won't have to wait 5min between each deploy. But, when using `functions.pubsub.topic('topicName').onPublish(...)`, it won't subscribe to the real prod messages, looks like it will only subscribe to the dev env ones.

I want to, in my firebase emulated Sub/Pub, subscribe to prod messages. Is it possible to do it? How?

Answer (score 1):

Still haven't found an "official" way.

What I am doing for now is use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), get the local function url and then enter it in Pub/Sub Subscription in Push mode. It's a longer way and will require updating the ngrok url for each session (as its url changes in free tier), and also to get the data, `JSON.parse(Buffer.from(req.body.message.data, 'base64').toString('utf-8'))` and still haven't found a way to auth the JWT auth  from request.

But, I can now get the Prod messages from my Firebase Emulator, as I want. You may comment here to ask for further infos about that workaround of mine.